# React Native dimond grid of buttons

Tags: react-native

I'm making a game in React Native. Part of the game includes a grid of buttons in a dimond shape similar to this:
[image]

To make it more complex, the assets are in SVG format. Although I am able to make a button using an SVG, what I'm a bit stumped on is laying out the buttons in this dimond shape, with an SVG layer behind it, and keeping that shape, with the buttons overlayed intact with different screen sizes.

Does anyone have experiece with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with transform like

```
<TouchableOpacity
    style={{
      height: 30,
      width: 30,
      marginVertical: 10,
      borderColor: 'black',
      borderWidth: 2,
      transform: [{ rotate: '45deg' }],
    }}
  />
```